# Issues connecting firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, visual-studio-code, gradle

[image]

Hi new to flutter creating an android app. Facing this issue when i tried to follow the steps on firebase in putting
id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
Error is preventing me from moving forward. Anyone have any idea?

I realize too that i am missing something like this
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

Wondering if this is important as well and if so, how can i fix this too